# ¡Existen recursos para aprender en Overflow para Teams?

Tags: bots

¿Que sucede si quiero mas información sobre Overflow para Teams?

No he utilizado aun Overflow para Teams, quisiera saber su finalidad y modo de uso para así sacarle mas provecho y hacer un buen uso de la misma.
Si existe mas informacion quisiera saber donde encontrarla.